# Ler todos os posts e comentários de um usuário do facebook?

Tags: facebook, get, web-crawler

Caros amigos,

Eu estou precisando de um help. Preciso fazer um crawler que ler todos os posts com mpremissão de amigos e seus comentários usando php.

Eu por meio dosdk-php consigo fazer um teste com os meus posts. Li da primeira página e segunda, mas não estou conseguindo ler os comentários.

Alguém sabe a rotina de ler todos os posts do mais atual até o último incluindo seus comentários???